# DEoptim strategy selection

Tags: r, optimization

I am not sure that this is particularly programming related, but was looking at a demo of parallel optimisation in a financial portfolio context using DEoptim, shown [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/DEoptim/sandbox/largeN_doSNOW.R?view=markup&revision=94&root=deoptim).

Which I found by looking at the presentation given [here](http://files.meetup.com/1772780/20120201_Ulrich_Parallel_DEoptim.pdf) and [here](http://blog.fosstrading.com/2012/03/deoptim-in-parallel.html).

And it seems that the `strategy` used is `strategy=6`, is there any particular reason why this one is "better" than the others? does it get to the global minimum faster? is it particularly good for portfolio optimisation problems?

Also as a separate note, how does one load into R the rda files that are suggested in the demo, that are used i.e. [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/DEoptim/sandbox/10y_returns.rda?root=deoptim&view=log). Becasue when clicking on download I get the `10y_return.gz` file, but don't know how to read it into R...help on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`strategy=6` is adaptive differential evolution by Zhang and Sanderson (2009). If the control parameter `c` is non-zero, then the crossover and mutation will be adjusted during the optimization. This can often speed convergence on particularly difficult objective functions/constraints, as is the case with the constrained portfolio optimization examples.

I get `10y_return.rda` when I click the download link. If you truly get a `.gz` file, then you just need to unzip it first.